# How to use tokio DuplexStream in spawned parallel tasks?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Suppose I use a pair of DuplexStreams in an application in order to allow bidirectional communication between server and client.

```rust
use use tokio::io::duplex;
let (upstream, dwstream) = duplex(64*1024);
```

Then I use dwstream to send data to the client and read the data sent by the client from dwstream.

If all these operations are executed in one async block, of course there is no problem. But now, for concurrency, I spawn a new async task for reading the dwstream, and in another task I need to write data to the dwstream from time to time.

In order to move the dwstream to the new task, I have to create an `Arc<Mutex<DuplexStream>>` object and then clone it before it supports Move.

However, in order to read in the read task, the object must always be `locked()`, which actually makes it impossible to get the object in the write task.

```rust
let (upstream, dwstream) = duplex(64*1024);
let dwrc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(dwstream));
let dwrc1 = dwrc.clone();
// write task
tokio::spwan(async move {
   ... some operations ...
   dwrc.lock().unwrap().write_all(...).await;
});
tokio::spwan(async move {
   let data = dwrc1.lock().unwrap().read().await; // here I think dwstream is locked for a long time.
});
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You're supposed to write to one stream in one task, and read from the other stream in the other task. Currently, you're writing to and reading from the same stream (`dwstream`) across the two tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to write to one stream in one task, and read from the other stream in the other task. Currently, you're writing to and reading from the same stream (`dwstream`) across the two tasks.

```
let (mut upstream, mut dwstream) = duplex(64*1024);
// write task
tokio::spawn(async move {
   upstream.write_all(b"abc").await;
});
// read task
tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut buf = vec![];
    dwstream.read(&mut buf).await;
});
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b80ab8d14da2e6fc64e00ae3cc6e4e9a)

Comment: thanks! Two more questions, if this is the server using upstream to write and dwstream to read. How does the client work with it then? And more, If I will start the write task for many times, how can I do?

Comment: After all, dwstream and upstream are each writable and readable.

Comment: If you want multiple write tasks (or multiple read tasks) then you'll need to wrap the stream in `Arc<Mutex<>>` and clone for each task, kind of like you had originally.

Comment: What do you mean by "client" and "server"? The duplex streams are meant for (possibly bi-directional) inter-task communication. Each duplex stream it gives you is bi-directional. You can write to the first and read from the second, but you can also write to the second and read from the first. You can do both back and forth, if you wish.

Comment: you can refer it: https://docs.rs/tokio/1.21.1/tokio/io/struct.DuplexStream.html#example . DuplexStream is a full duplex channel, every endpoint can both write and read. I want use upstream to read and write. But your code use up to write, dw to read.

Comment: Yes, you can write to client, then read from server. Then you can turn around and write to server, then read from client. Data travels either from client to server or from server to client. But you can't, for instance, write a certain data to client and then read that data from client.